# Modify pixel values in tensorflow

Tags: python, image, tensorflow, pixel

I am learning Tensorflow and Python. I tried reading an image from a file and then displaying that image using matplotlib. Here is my code.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf    
# read and decode the image
image_contents = tf.read_file('elephant.jpeg')
image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_contents, channels=3)

with tf.Session() as sess:  
    img = sess.run(image)
    print(img)
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.imshow(img)
    plt.show()
```

This also prints a huge array which I understand are the RGB values for each pixel. Now I am trying to modify pixel values individually. I can modify all the pixel values at once using tf operations but I am not able to operate on individual pixel values.

For example, I have been trying to make the image grayscale. So, I want to replace the R, G and B values with the average of R,G and B values of the pixel. How do I do that?

I also want to know if I should be focussing on Python or Tensorflow?

Answer (score 1):

You can directly convert the image to grayscale with Pillow

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open('/some path/image.png').convert('L')
```

I prefer preprocessing images with numpy before feeding them into tensorflow.
I am not sure which shape your array has, i would suggest to convert the image to a 2 dim np array. In the case below i am converting a list of pixels (shape=[784]) to an array with shape=28x28. Afterwards you can directly perform operations on each pixel.

```
 image = np.reshape(img, (28,28)).astype(np.uint8)
```